# Замена изображения, изображением на которое навели курсор

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, img

Представим что есть один главный блок, и ниже пару блоков поменьше.
В них лежат изображения.

```
.main>img
   .small>img
   .small>img
   .small>img
   .small>img
```

Задача в том, что бы при наведении на маленькие блоки, их img передавался на главный, и там уже транслировался.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.small-img').hover(function() {
  document.getElementById('big-img').src = this.src;
});
$('.small-img').mouseout(function() {
  document.getElementById('big-img').src = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mK72EwuxZAU/hqdefault.jpg';
});
```

```css
.big-block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#big-img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.small-block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.small-img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="big-block">
  <img id="big-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mK72EwuxZAU/hqdefault.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="small-block">
  <img class="small-img" src="https://cs8.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2016/05/09/11/1462820965116271616.jpg" />
  <img class="small-img" src="https://www.meme-arsenal.com/memes/876041c5669352bb985e3a11eda018b7.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Я тебе благодарен, искреннее спасибо.